# How to format the php code to display this better

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from page';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($result)) {
    echo '<table><tr>';
    foreach ($rows[0] as $columnName => $value) {
        echo '<th>' . $columnName . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
        }
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

This code is working fine. But since my table is huge, it is appearing to be very very clumsy - almost unreadable. And I don't know how to make it appear better. I tried adding spaces and tabs but to no use. I can't understand how to do it. I got this code from my friend. Can anyone modify the code so as to add at least a tab space between every column. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a question about css/html rather than php. For example `table { width:100%; }`

Comment: `css` is a great styling language, you should look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example do the following:
instead of

```
echo '<table><tr>';
```

use

```
echo '<table border="1"><tr>';
```

It will put border on your table and it will be easier to differentiate between cells